# Create a group_column to group the data with at least 1 common elements

Tags: python, networking, pyspark

I have a data frame like this:

```
data = [("A",11),("A",12),("B",12),("B",14),("C",9),("C",7),("D",50),("D",7)]
columns= ["Worker","Monthly_Salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
```

Now, I would like to create a group_column to group the data: if any workers that have at least 1 same element of salary, they will be collected into 1 group.

For example: A and B both have 12 as salary, so A1, A2 and B1, B2 are put into Group 1 as in the image.
I have tried to generate network plot but did not success. Just wonder if anyone can help me with this.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Window funtions:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

groups = df\
            .withColumn('Count', F.approx_count_distinct('Worker').over(W.partitionBy('Monthly_Salary')))\
            .filter(F.col('Count')>1)\
            .withColumn("Group", F.dense_rank().over(W.orderBy('Monthly_Salary')))\
            .select('Worker', 'Group')

jonied_df = df\
  .join(groups, 'Worker', 'left')


final_df = jonied_df\
  .join(
        jonied_df\
          .select('Group')\
          .dropDuplicates()\
          .withColumn('Group_new', F.monotonically_increasing_id()+1)
        ,on = 'Group'
        )\
  .drop('Group')\
  .orderBy('Worker')

final_df.show()

+------+--------------+---------+
|Worker|Monthly_Salary|Group_new|
+------+--------------+---------+
|     A|            11|        1|
|     A|            12|        1|
|     B|            14|        1|
|     B|            12|        1|
|     C|             7|        2|
|     C|             9|        2|
|     D|            50|        2|
|     D|             7|        2|
+------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks Luiz Viola. It works well for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Well - if I understood it correctly - what you have is a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) and what you want is to find all connected components and assign an unique value to each of them. There is a powerful library named [networkx](https://networkx.org/) that does this. Definitely check it out.

You could, for instance, first convert your spark data frame to a pandas data frame. Then, you could basically apply the following code:

```py
import networkx as nx

graph_as_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'worker': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD'], 'salary': [11, 12, 12, 14, 9, 7, 50, 7]})

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(graph_as_df.drop_duplicates().to_numpy().tolist())

connected_components = list(nx.connected_components(G))


for i, components in enumerate(connected_components):
    components = list(components)
    # The next line is more precise but not required
    # graph_as_df.loc[(graph_as_df['worker'].isin(components)) | (graph_as_df['salary'].isin(components))] = i
    graph_as_df.loc[graph_as_df['worker'].isin(components), "group"] = i + 1
    
graph_as_df['group'] = graph_as_df['group'].astype(int)
graph_as_df

-----------------------------------------------------
    worker  salary  group
0   A       11      1
1   A       12      1
2   B       12      1
3   B       14      1
4   CC      9       2
5   CC      7       2
6   DD      50      2
7   DD      7       2
-----------------------------------------------------
```

where `graph_as_df` is your `pd.DataFrame`. Afterwards, you could convert it back to a spark data frame. I faced a similar problem and solved it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570758/speeding-up-pandas-column-operation-based-on-several-rules) post. If you do not want to convert your spark data frame to a pandas data frame you have to adjust this code accordingly.